# Constructing a package for simple imports

Tags: python, python-packaging

The Python standard library has functions designed to be imported and used simply. for example:

```
import re
m = re.search('foo')
```

The package documentation https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages has an example subpackage layout.  But let's simplify that to have only a single package with no subpackages:

```
sound/                  Top-level package
    __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
    wavread.py
    wavwrite.py
    ...
```

Our hypothetical wavread.py defines a function:

```
def read_wav(name):
    return 'Hello ' + name
```

Functions in this package are called with:

1. a package name (sound)
2. a file name (wavread)
3. a function name defined within the file (read_wav())

for example:

```
import sound.wavread

sf = sound.wavread.read_wav('foo')
```

or:

```
import sound.wavread as sound

sf = sound.read_wav('foo')
```

---

**Question:** How should one create a package so that it can be both imported and used simply, without exposing python filenames (e.g., `wavread`) to the package user?  One could create a "package" that is a single file containing all of its functions, but one huge file isn't very modular.  What is the Pythonic way to structure a complex package for both ease of use and ease of maintenance?

**Desired user code:**

```
import sound

sf = sound.read_wav('foo')
```

Comment: depends on how *complex* the package you are trying to create, does it have other dependencies on other files/import from different folders, if so then it probably won't be a great idea to depend on that one main package rather break into components. The example you have shown is good enough to demonstrate creating the package.

Comment: `read_wav` is that a function or a file within the `sound` dir, if not you could do `from sound import *`, it's a little unclear.

Comment: The goal is to have a simple `import x`, not `from x import y` or `import x as y`.   Most standard library functions don't use those types of imports, yet they contain many functions that might best be split into multiple files.

Comment: see answer below, it should be done that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `__init__.py` do the following:

```
from .wavread import * #or only the functions you want to export from  wavread.py
from .wavwrite import *
# and so on for all files that implement function of the sound module
```

This way user of sound module can do:
`from sound import *` or `from sound import read_wav`
or

```
import sound
# ...
sf = sound.read_wav('foo')
```

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure I understand your comment. With what I wrote you can simply do `import sound` and then `sound.read_wav`. What is missing?

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm.  The package page describes creating an `__all__` variable in init.py, but simple imports are kind of buried in the description.